# How to show default value in Lightning:input?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, inputfield

I want to show default value as 0.0 in lightning:input field on page load.

I don't want it to be a placeholder.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

According to SF [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleInputNumber), it is possible to be done without placeholder, just put default value in **value** field:

```
<lightning:input type="number" name="input2" label="Number field with a predefined value" value="0.0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/03610bb980aaddc26be20555436d677725334f2d/edit) to get an sample example of Number field with a predefined value in Lightning Web Component.

[image]

value property of lightning-input component specifies the value of an input element.

Reference:- [Lightning Web Component Input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example)

if you are dealing with Lightning Data service and want to pre-populate the field value of [lightning-input-field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation), You can again use the value property of it to pre-populate.

```
         <lightning-record-edit-form
                    id="recordViewForm"
                    record-id="003R00000000000000"
                    record-type-id="012R00000000000000"
                    object-api-name="Contact">
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="NumberField__c" value="0.0">
            </lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-button type="submit"
                        label="Update record"
                        class="slds-m-top_medium">
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
```